# Run two independent tomcat servers within IDEA

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I need a tip about running two tomcat servers: how can I run two contexts from two different tomcat servers, using IDEA (or not using it though...)
How I should configure my tomcats and IDEA? Please, give a tip or some links on working manuals about that case.

I use Windows 7, Tomcat 6, IDEA 14 <s>, Java 6 :'(</s>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing you must change is your run/debug config. Http port and jmx port must be different for two different tomcats.
i.e.

```
first tomcat:
http port: 8081
jmx port: 1099

second tomcat:
http port: 8082
jmx port: 1100
```

Comment: ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:690]

Comment: can you grep processes to see if something already running on these ports?

Comment: I don't know why I couldn't do it in the past, but now it's working. I have two different folders with tomcats. Just hit 'edit run/debug configuration' -> configure tomcat and set tomcat folder for desired tomcat. And different ports as you said.